# Issue with setting up EditText to accept Double Values

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext

I set up my EditText fields into `android:inputType="numberSigned"` in XML file. But it seems like it is only accepting non floating values, because it does not allow the user to enter the floating point (dot). But actually, I must have `double` values, so it must support double values. How can I do it? I prefer a way in XML. Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

This will allow you to enter Double Values

Comment: @Yohan its my pleasure buddy.